# Filtering out rows that have an identical column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a complex query which returns a table with a column that has some duplicate values, and a second column with integers.

Here is a simple representation of what the data looks like:

```
col1   col2
===========
A      null
A      1
A      1
A      2
A      3

B      2
B      3

C      4

D      null
```

My requirement is to select all rows whose col2 value is null or the minimum when grouped by col1.

Thus, my expected result is:

```
col1   col2
===========
A      null
A      1
A      1

B      2

C      4

D      null
```

In other words, for each distinct value in col1, find the corresponding minimum in col2, and filter out any rows which are NOT NULL and greater than that value.

I tried doing grouping but that of course combines the rows. I feel like there's a somewhat straightforward solution here that I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `or` and a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.col2 is null or
      t.col2 = (select min(t2.col2) from t t2 where t2.col1 = t.col1);
```

Repeating a complex query is cumbersome.  You can also do this with window functions:

```
select col1, col2
from (select t.*, min(col2) over (partition by col1) as min_col2
      from t
     ) t
where col2 is null or col2 = min_col2;
```

Comment: Didn't know about `PARTITION BY`. That's perfect, thanks!

Comment: Note that the PARTITION BY syntax required MySQL 8.0.2 or later.

Comment: @BillKarwin That would explain why I didn't know about it then. We are using 5.6 unfortunately.

Comment: Accepted this even though it doesn't apply to my particular use case, which is my fault for not specifying in the question. Hopefully it's useful to someone else.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename x
  where x.col1 = t.col1 and x.col2 < t.col2
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rXSuxLDDJqx53tdvYuWECQ/0).
Results:

```
| col1 | col2 |
| ---- | ---- |
| A    | null |
| A    | 1    |
| A    | 1    |
| B    | 2    |
| C    | 4    |
| D    | null |
```

Comment: Though not strictly necessary, I added the alias `x` for clarity. +1

Comment: While this is concise, the actual query I'm using is pulling from dozens of tables, so I need to be able to run the query once and then filter it down. That is, I would need to substitute "tablename" for the complex query twice.